# Strange flickering while modeling in Blender 2.8 beta

Tags: modeling, faces

So, while modeling simple building, I came across some strangle flickering on faces, which is strange for me.
There is no overlapping, so "z-fight" is not the cause here.
Flickering is visible with solid or rendered -- no matter which.

I have blender 2.8 beta by 27.02.2019 version

I inserted images and .blend file, so please look at them :)
[image]
[image: flicker on foot of quad table]

[image: flickering on the edge of building]

Comment: Strangely -- I've created new file and imported same models -- problem somehow solved.
But what was causing this is a mystery for me (maybe it was because of animation?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flickering was because your **Clip Start** distance was way to small. This setting can be found in the **View** menu of the **Properties** side panel. The **N** key to toggle view or hide panel.

It was set at 0.00002m :
[image]

Increasing the distance a little to 0.1m .........
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks!
Didn't`t know clipping can cause this...